# Wordpress Contribution Form - how to suppress Leave Page Warning

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, contribution-page

I found a note about suppressing the leave page alert using  Joomla. Does it applies to sites using WordPress?

On our WordPress contribution page we give a PayPal Option.
The user fills in the donation amount then selects the Pay with PayPal radio button.
When the user hits Confirm Contribution - a javascript alert pops up warning

---

Leave Page?

Changes you made may not be saved.

**Leave**    **Cancel**

---

Is there a way to not have the javascript alert, and just go to PayPal?

The other answer mentions modifying the Profile. As best I know we are not using a Profile.

Comment: Can you note the WP and CiviCRM versions as well as if this affects all browsers?   If you can link to the other answer regarding profiles that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Are you using stripe payment processor?

Comment: Here is the other answer https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7087/how-do-i-suppress-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-leave-this-page-popup-from-cont?rq=1

Comment: I am using the stripe payment processor  and paypal