# CiviEvent: selecting "Pay later" option causes the browser to show "are you sure you want to leave this site"? message

Tags: civievent, registration, paylater

I have an odd problem with my CiviEvent registration.

When a user fills out a registration form and selects the "Pay later" payment option, on clicking "Continue" the browser throws an "are you sure you want to leave this page" message. (Everything works if the user then clicks "OK", it's just confusing to the user to see a message "you may lose any changes on this page".)  If they choose the online payment option and fill out the billing information, "Continue" properly takes them to the next confirmation page.

The only other question I've found that discusses this is

[How do I suppress the "are you sure you want to leave this page" popup from contribution page](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7087/how-do-i-suppress-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-leave-this-page-popup-from-cont)

and it seems I can disable the message by manipulating the onbeforeunload JS function (which I will try) but I'd really like to know what the core problem is instead of just putting a band-aid on it :-)

System deets: Joomla 3.8.12, CiviCRM 5.3.1

Comment: Are you using stripe payment method?

Comment: So, commenting out the onbeforeunload function does indeed suppress this message.  However, i'm still not sure why changing the payment option would trigger this message.

Comment: Yes I am Pradeep! Does that have something to do with it?

Comment: We are seeing this issue with Authorize.net as-well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are you using Stripe payment processor extension as one of the payment gateway. There is a known issue reported by a user facing similar problem and have been issues for other users also. As mentioned in info.xml Stripe extension supports till 5.0 and might have not tested fully for 5.3. The only solution I would give is to upgrade stripe if you haven't to 5.0 or from https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe or wait until some one from Maintainer fixes the problem.

> You can try if its a stripe problem by disabling the extension and
>   submitting the form.

Pradeep

Comment: Hmmm good to know. I'm currently running the 5.0 version (latest) offered on the web UI installer.