# 'Are you sure you want to leave this site' popup message issue on event and contribution forms

Tags: civievent

We have an issue where whenever a user tries to move to the confirmation page of an event registration (or contribution) page they are getting the browser message 'Are you sure you want to leave this site' popup.

See https://portal.communityfirstyorkshire.org.uk/civicrm/event/register?id=80&reset=1. Try to complete the form and continue.

Has anyone else seen this issue. There is no custom code on this system which would affect this functionality.

Comment: Are you using strip payment processor?

Comment: Not an answer as such, but something's not setting `data-warn-changes="true"` on the form element. Doing so manually makes the form submit without the warning.

Comment: Which civicrm version and drupal version is installed?

Comment: have seen discussion about this elsewhere - not this but will link to it anyway - https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26905/civievent-selecting-pay-later-option-causes-the-browser-to-show-are-you-sure

Comment: Ah, yes it is something to do with stripe. Non paid events don't have this issue.